# mongoose.connect(uri, ConnectOptions) does not recognize useNewUrlParser and other options

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

My GitHub repo: https://github.com/safiullah7/legan

Branch: redux

I'm following this tutorial: https://tomanagle.medium.com/build-a-rest-api-with-node-js-typescript-mongodb-b6c898d70d61
and I'm unable to connect to my mongodb.
Here's my code file where I'm trying to connect with the mongodb:

```
import config from "config";
import log from "../logger";

function connect() {
  const dbUri = config.get("dbUri") as string;

  return mongoose
    .connect(dbUri, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    .then(() => {
      log.info("Database connected");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      log.error("db error", error);
      process.exit(1);
    });
}

export default connect;
```

Compiler gives the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(uri: string, callback: CallbackWithoutResult): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ useNewUrlParser: boolean; useUnifiedTopology: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CallbackWithoutResult'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'useNewUrlParser' does not exist in type 'CallbackWithoutResult'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(uri: string, options?: ConnectOptions | undefined): Promise<typeof import("mongoose")>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ useNewUrlParser: boolean; useUnifiedTopology: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConnectOptions'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'useNewUrlParser' does not exist in type 'ConnectOptions'.
```

I'm new to typescript and node/mongoos. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: You can try this from the Mongoose docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html

Comment: Refer to a full list of supported `options`: [MongoDB Node.js driver docs for connect()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/MongoClient.html#connect)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The new version of `mongoose` (the latest version when I wrote this post is `6.0.2`) has the following type definitions for the `connect()` function.

```
/** Opens Mongoose's default connection to MongoDB, see [connections docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) */
export function connect(uri: string, options: ConnectOptions, callback: CallbackWithoutResult): void;
export function connect(uri: string, callback: CallbackWithoutResult): void;
export function connect(uri: string, options?: ConnectOptions): Promise<Mongoose>;
```

The `options object` you're passing to the `connect()` function

```
{
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
}
```

is, therefore, should have a type of `ConnectOptions`.

Current definition of the `ConnectOptions` is as follows:

```
interface ConnectOptions extends mongodb.MongoClientOptions {
  /** Set to false to [disable buffering](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html#callback_never_executes) on all models associated with this connection. */
  bufferCommands?: boolean;
  /** The name of the database you want to use. If not provided, Mongoose uses the database name from connection string. */
  dbName?: string;
  /** username for authentication, equivalent to `options.auth.user`. Maintained for backwards compatibility. */
  user?: string;
  /** password for authentication, equivalent to `options.auth.password`. Maintained for backwards compatibility. */
  pass?: string;
  /** Set to false to disable automatic index creation for all models associated with this connection. */
  autoIndex?: boolean;
  /** Set to `true` to make Mongoose automatically call `createCollection()` on every model created on this connection. */
  autoCreate?: boolean;
}
```

Looking at the new definition of the `connect` and `ConnectOptions`, we can see that there is no definition of `useNewUrlParser` or `useUnifiedTopology` inside the `ConnectOptions`. That is the reason we got such an error. You can delete the options `useNewUrlParser: true,` and `useUnifiedTopology: true,` and your code should be able to connect to your MongoDB. If you want to pass in some options to the `connect()` function, then they should follow the new type definition of the `ConnectOptions`.

Comment: It's nice that you show the way one would find out by oneself how to properly use the function. Maybe you could add to your answer that according to the documentation these flags are now set by default and hence are no longer available through the client options.

Answer (score 32):

You can change your mongoose.connect function to:

```
mongoose.connect(dbUri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
} as ConnectOptions)
```

This is the simplest way

Comment: from where do we have to import ConnectOptions?

Comment: import mongoose, { ConnectOptions } from 'mongoose';

Answer (score 21):

**UPDATE: Clarifying this answer as a reference for future readers.**

This answer applies if you are using Mongoose v6+.

Other answers explain how to expand typescript to accept useNewUrlParser and other options, which would resolve the original question.

However, as per Mongoose documentation, if you are using Mongoose v6+, these options are NO longer required, as they have been included as defaults.

As per Mongoose migration guide to version 6:

> useNewUrlParser, useUnifiedTopology, useFindAndModify, and
> useCreateIndex are no longer supported options. Mongoose 6 always
> behaves as if useNewUrlParser, useUnifiedTopology, and useCreateIndex
> are true, and useFindAndModify is false. Please remove these options
> from your code.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#no-more-deprecation-warning-options

Therefore, it is no longer necessary to include these options. I would imagine this is why they are no longer included in ConnectOptions type.

If you are using an older version of Mongoose, refer to the other answers for how to expand ConnectOptions type to allow for these options.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30316496)

Comment: This is the real answer. Old versions of mongo docs promoted the use of useNewUrlParser, etc so this explains the error the user is seeing. Not sure why you have a problem with this @mbuechmann

Comment: I also hit the same problem as @SU7 while following another Tom Nagal tutorial [link](https://tomanagle.medium.com/build-deploy-a-full-stack-url-shortener-with-node-js-react-typescript-mongodb-72b5b8885024). Tom says run `yarn add mongoose` in both. This gets the latest version (now 6+), while the tutorial code appears to have been written with 5+. This mongoose version mismatch results in the compilation error. The fix is to remove the options as indicated by @Nickolai and @Hoang. You could pin your version of mongoose to 5+ in package.json, but remove the options object was a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

So far, just waiting for new update from mongoose, in the meantime there is a workaround may help

```
import { ConnectionOptions, connect } from "mongoose"

type ConnectionOptionsExtend = {
  useNewUrlParser: boolean
  useUnifiedTopology: boolean
}

const options: ConnectionOptions & ConnectionOptionsExtend = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  authSource: "admin",
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  user,
  pass
}

await connect(uri, options)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const con = await mongoose.connect((process.env.MONGO_URI as string), {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
} as ConnectOptions)
```

The options `usecreateindex`, `usefindandmodify` are not supported.